# Javafx does not accept other fonts or languages in textArea of Text Field

Tags: javafx, textarea

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
public class textareasss extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    GridPane p = new GridPane();
    TextArea tx= new TextArea();
    p.add(tx,0,0);
    
    Scene sce = new Scene(p,600,600);
    stage.setScene(sce);
    stage.show();
 }
 }
```

[Link to the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUZzQ.png)

Everytime i paste text in javafx Text Area or TextField, the text is not displayed but rather symbols like this:????.

Comment: java naming conventions please ..

Comment: I am new to javafx but the same error occurs in other javafx classes as well

Comment: Have you considered that maybe the installed font (that JavaFX is able to pick up from your PC) is not able to display it? Try adding a font, applying it to all text fields (via CSS or code) and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it works, nothing wrong with JavaFX not accepting fonts or languages

this is what i used :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        TextArea text= new TextArea();
        gridpane.add(text,0,0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane,600,600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and this is the output i got :

[TextArea containing text in many languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09uIv.png)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1and java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing), on my macbook.